# SSH - Auth fail when fetch config from config repository

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, repository

I have problem with SSH, when I am trying to fetch data from config repository.

I can clone repository via SSH, GitLab shows that my keys were used, when I cloned repository.
I even created two different keys for root and user, and both were used, and let me clone my repo.

When I try to run configService i just get: git@(RepoWithConfig)gitlab.com:: Auth fail.

For me, it looks like problem with SSH.

I remember, that my friend had similar problem, and he solved it, by... creating new keys, and finally, after x tries it worked, but I don't want to sit and spend a few days trying new keys.

As you can read above, I use GitLab and my system is Ubuntu(but the friend had problem on Windows, so I don't think it's a problem).

I can clone every repository which I have granted permission in GitLab, and I have permission to this repository. Also, I don't think it is problem with code, because earlier when I worked in this project, everything was good, and now my friends who work with me, don't have any problems.

I will be grateful for every hint.

Comment: What is "configService" in the context of GitLab?

Comment: configService is my service with configuration, it is on GitLab repository, which contain configuration of our application. I have full permission to this repository, I even could clone it via SSH to my system, but still, when app try to run this service, only I got is: Auth fail.